# How to tell `getchar()` to go back to the beginning of the buffer?

Tags: c, getchar

I am learning C from "The C Programming Language" and I have ran into something with `getchar()` that confuses me. Apparently, when I call `getchar()` in a program, the input text is stored in a buffer and then `getchar()` reads the characters in this buffer one by one until it sees `EOF`. Is it possible for me to instruct `getchar()` to perform this process a second time on the same buffer? For instance, the second loop in the following program will not run for me. Is it possible to "reset" `getchar()` after the first loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ int c,d;
  c = d = 0;

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) printf("foo");

  while((d = getchar()) != EOF) printf("bar");
}
```

Comment: `stored in a buffer`... **specifically** , input buffer, i.e., the one associated with `stdin`...

Comment: No. The real question is **Why**?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `EOF` is end of file, aka, *no more input*, period.

Comment: Is there something in particular about `getchar()` that does not allow me to do this? 

I am doing exercise 1-13 from "The C Programming Language" and I am trying to print a histogram of length of words in the input. In order to get the histogram to align properly, I am looping over the input to find the length of the longest word and then looping again to print the histogram. I thought I should find out why I am getting things wrong before trying another way. EDIT: I should add that I'm not after a solution to the exercise -- I want to learn about `getchar()`.

Comment: `getchar` reads from the `stdin`, and data, once read, is "lost". So store the input in a variable and use it. But reading each word and recording the data accordingly is better.

Comment: with a file on disk, you could use `rewind()` to read it again. But your standard input is not a file, just a stream. If you want to process input from the user (or, from a pipe) multiple times, you have to store it yourself.

Comment: Streams of chars don't have a start point, (except opening the stream), so you cannot go back to it.  Just because there is some internal buffering optimization to the stream implementation does not change that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `getchar()` that is buffered, but your terminal. Once you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the terminal sends the whole line you typed *at once* to your program. From your program's point of view, there's no buffer, you just sat still for ten seconds, then typed a whole sentence in a blink.

You can verify that by crafting a loop that `getchar()`'s, and outputs the character it received immediately : the output will *not* be interleaved with the input, it will only appear once you've pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Thus, if you want to reuse what you know is a buffer, you need your program to read it into an actual buffer on its side via [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and then use that buffer as desired.

Comment: Note that this requires your environment to conform to *POSIX.1-2008*. If you want something working with any standard C implementation, use `fgets()` with a reasonably large buffer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oops ! `getline()` being in `<stdio.h>` led me to believe it was standard C. Thank you !

Comment: If you're using `glibc`, `<stdio.h>` exposes this only when feature test macros are set appropriately, so compiling with e.g. `gcc -std=c99 -Wall` without a `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` will result in an *implicit function declaration* warning (without any further arguments, `gcc` will implicitly use any `glibc` features available)

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple getchar() doesn't read in a buffer, but in the keyboard input stream, normally called **stdin** (standard input).

getchar() doesn't peek a char from the stream, but **consumes** a char for each call that means **read & remove** the char from the stream.
So when you're at end of stream you'll get an eof (end of file) that informs you that there are no more chars in it.

Then the stdin is normally **line buffered** meaning that a full input line, a series of chars terminated by a newline, is made available at time.